# Best way to aggregate data - Update query or subquery?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to aggregate some customer order data into one table for analysis. The data is the number of products a customer orders, then trying to determine whether the order is a small, medium, or large order, then determine the total products they bought and the cost of the order by `OrderSize`.

Small order - 1 - 2 products
Medium order - 3 - 4 products
Large Order - >=5 products

Here is the data:

```
CustomerID  OrderID   OrderSize OrderTotal
1           800       1         $20
2           801       1         $10
3           802       4         $85
1           803       1         $30
2           804       8         $120
3           805       1         $40
```

Here is the table I am attempting to build (easier to just post an image):
[image: Table Screenshot]

I could run an update query like this to populate the table:

-- Build the table --

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SmallOrderCount int,
    SmallOrderProducts int,
    SmallOrderTotal money,
    MedOrderCount int,
    MedOrderProducts int,
    MedOrderTotal money,
    LargeOrderCount int,
    LargeOrderProducts int,
    LargeOrderTotal money
);
```

-- Insert the unique customers --

```
INSERT INTO Customers
SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

-- Update to populate the order information --

```
UPDATE Customers
SET SmallOrderCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM Orders WHERE OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID);

UPDATE Customers 
SET SmallOrderProducts = (SELECT sum(OrderSize) FROM Orders WHERE OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID);

UPDATE Customers 
SET SmallOrderTotal = (SELECT sum(OrderTotal) FROM Orders WHERE OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID);
```

Then I could repeat this for the remaining 6 columns.

However, this seems like a lot of work. Is there a way to populate my `Customer` table using a subquery that may be less work?  Or is my approach above the most direct?

Comment: As an aside: Why would you define `CustomerID varchar(10)`? The data looks like `integer` should do a better job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do **all** of it in one INSERT command with CASE statements:

```
INSERT INTO Customers
SELECT CustomerID
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SmallOrderCount
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN OrderSize ELSE 0 END) AS SmallOrderProducts
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN OrderTotal ELSE 0 END) AS SmallOrderTotal
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MedOrderCount
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN OrderSize ELSE 0 END) AS MedOrderProducts
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN OrderTotal ELSE 0 END) AS MedOrderTotal
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LargeOrderCount
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize > 4 THEN OrderSize ELSE 0 END) AS LargeOrderProducts
      ,sum(CASE WHEN OrderSize > 4 THEN OrderTotal ELSE 0 END) AS LargeOrderTotal
FROM   Orders
GROUP  BY CustomerID;
```

See this [**working demo for the full query on data.SE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123017/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I had no idea data.se.com existed!

Comment: @mikebmassey: It's handy for demonstrating SQL Server queries. The original purpose is to let users query the SE database, though. Data is synced every month or so.

Answer (score 1):

One `insert` should be enough:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID,SmallOrderCount,SmallOrderProducts,
   SmallOrderTotal)     
SELECT a.CustomerID, COUNT(a.*) as cnt, sum(a.OrderSize) as OrderSize,
    sum(a.OrderTotal) as OrderTotal 
   FROM Orders a
   WHERE a.OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
   GROUP BY a.CustomerID
```

The query above will insert only customers whose order size is between 1 and 2. If you need to insert others as well, you can use :

```
INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID,SmallOrderCount,SmallOrderProducts,
   SmallOrderTotal)     
SELECT a.CustomerID, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN  a.OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2  THEN 1 END) as cnt, 
sum(CASE WHEN  a.OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2  THEN a.OrderSize ELSE 0 END) as OrderSize,
sum(CASE WHEN  a.OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2  THEN a.OrderTotal ELSE 0 END ) as OrderTotal 
FROM Orders a
GROUP BY a.CustomerID
```

Comment: this would still require more than one update query then for each group, correct?  a.OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2, a.OrderSize Between 3 AND 4, a.OrderSize >= 5, just run that 3 times?

Comment: This only works for the first three columns (`Small*`), and cannot do the whole job in one INSERT as advertised.

Comment: @mikebmassey: One query, just 6 more fields in `SELECT` (3 for medium, 3 for large). Sorry, I missed breakdown in your question, so I posted just for small. Medium and large are similar, just different conditions in `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

I'd only create a single query (which can be used as view) for that and not a whole new persisted table.

```
WITH cteOrders AS (
    SELECT CustomerID,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN OrderSize END SmallOrderProducts,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN OrderTotal END SmallOrderTotal,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN OrderSize END MediumOrderProducts,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN OrderTotal END MediumOrderTotal,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize > 4 THEN OrderSize END LargeOrderProducts,
        CASE WHEN OrderSize > 4 THEN OrderTotal END LargeOrderTotal
    FROM Orders
)
SELECT CustomerID,
        COUNT(SmallOrderProducts) SmallOrderCount,
        COALESCE(SUM(SmallOrderProducts), 0) SmallOrderProducts,
        COALESCE(SUM(SmallOrderTotal), 0) SmallOrderTotal,
        COUNT(MediumOrderProducts) MediumOrderCount,
        COALESCE(SUM(MediumOrderProducts), 0) MediumOrderProducts,
        COALESCE(SUM(MediumOrderTotal), 0) MediumOrderTotal,
        COUNT(LargeOrderProducts) LargeOrderCount,
        COALESCE(SUM(LargeOrderProducts), 0) LargeOrderProducts,
        COALESCE(SUM(LargeOrderTotal), 0) LargeOrderTotal
    FROM cteOrders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using single INSERT INTO SELECT statement

```
INSERT INTO Customers
SELECT * ,
 (SELECT count(*) FROM Orders WHERE OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Orders.CustomerID = CustomerID),
 (SELECT sum(OrderSize) FROM Orders WHERE OrderSize BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Orders.CustomerID  = CustomerID)

 FROM CUSTOMERS
```